# change orientation when video is finished in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

I think my coding on done button is not working as i am changing my screen orientation when video is starting and when video is finished i need to come back to my normal orientation my coding is.

```
vid = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
//[self presentModalViewController:vid animated:YES];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:vid];

NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(donebutton) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:vid];
```

and then the coding done button method

```
-(void) donebutton{
     NSLog(@"done");
     NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

Comment: you can implement orientation change code in "MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification"  method to set normal orientation on movie finish.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will help you to change device orientation when a video playing is completed.

```
-(void)playVideo {
      moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
             addObserver:self
             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
             object:moviePlayer];

     [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}


- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification {

moviePlayer = [notification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 removeObserver:self
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:moviePlayer];
// If the moviePlayer.view was added to full screen, it needs to be removed

moviePlayer.fullscreen = NO;

}
```

Comment: there is no property as moviePlayer.fullscreen which is in my case vid.fullscreen there is no such property

Comment: its not even reaching the method `moviePlaybackDidFinish`